# Typescript pass generic to Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to pass a generic type from the child class to a property.

```
interface MyInterface { 
    method(): void;
}

class B<P> {

    entities = new Map<number, P>();
}

class C<P = MyInterface> extends B<P> {

    click() {
      this.entities.get(1).method();
    }
}
```

I'm expecting each entity to be of type `MyInterface`, but I'm getting a type error:

> Property method() doesn't exist on type P

What is the issue?

Comment: I think you mean `C<P = MyInterface >` not `C<P = A>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `P = MyInterface` does not mean any passed in `P` must extend `MyInterface`. For example with no other constraints, this would also be valid:

```
new C<{ noMethod() : void }>();
```

You need to add a constraint to `P` to say that any passed in `P` must extend `MyInterface`, and you can keep `MyInterface` as a default as well.

```
interface MyInterface {
  method(): void;
}

class B<P> {

  entities = new Map<number, P>();
}

class C<P extends MyInterface = MyInterface> extends B<P> {

  click() {
    this.entities.get(1).method();
  }
}
```